# How to unit test API calls with mocked fetch() in react-native with Jest

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

In React Native I use `fetch` to perform network requests, however `fetch` is not an explicitly required module, so it is seemingly impossible to mock in Jest.

Even trying to call a method which uses `fetch` in a test will result in:

> ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

Is there a way to test such API requests in react native with Jest?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Inside your test case you can mock any function you want by using Jest's mocks:

```js
fetch = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve());
```

This approach works only for the promise-based test cases (see `pit` in the Jest docs).

As far as `fetch` is an async function, you need to run all your tests using `pit` (read more about async tests [here](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-async.html)).

Comment: FYI you can now use `it` by returning a Promise.

Comment: How is this fetch variable then used? If it is global does it interfere with other tests? Many other replies suggest to modify global.fetch with this but I'd like to not do that

Comment: @ColinD This override will be limited to the scope of the function/file. If you want to overwrite it only in one test, you might consider using the snippet above in the scope of `it` function.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am thinking though that if you use it in the context of a it(), then it will not truly be local to that it function, because it will be modifying the global fetch. I am thinking that perhaps the way to do it properly is to mock an import, and have code that relies on fetch to get it from an import e.g.

codeundertest.js
import fetch from 'myfetch'

codeundertest.test.js
jest.mock('./myfetch', () => Promise.resolve({ hello: 'world' });

Comment: Oh, you're right. Sorry for the misleading information. You can also use `afterEach` to restore the mock. For example, in the body of `describe` you can `const originalFetch = fetch` and then in `afterEach` run `fetch = originalFetch` and then safely override `fetch` inside `it` as shown above.

Comment: Like other comments say, what are you supposed to do with this? Do you pass it in as a prop, define it globally somewhere? it seems like if someone is able to take this and implement it with such little context, they likely already knew to use. People who dont know how to mock a fetch wont have a clue what to do with this.

Answer (score 24):

Another approach where you mock the global `fetch` object:

```js
const mockSuccesfulResponse = (
  status = 200,
  method = RequestType.GET,
  returnBody?: object
) => {
  global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve({
        ok: true,
        status,
        json: () => {
          return returnBody ? returnBody : {};
        },
      });
    });
  });
};
```

The above helper method can be modified any way you want :-) Hope it helps someone

Comment: global.fetch = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()); this works too!

Comment: I'd use `json: () => Promise.resolve({ ... })` to ensure `.then` works in addition to `await`.

Comment: that's a stub not a mock

Answer (score 7):

Rather than rolling your own mock, you can use the [jest-fetch-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-fetch-mock) npm package to override the global fetch object. That package allows you to set up fake responses and verify sent requests. See that link for extensive usage examples.

Comment: Alternatively, your mock doesn't have to be Jest-specific. [fetch-mock](http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/) has a very nice API and is more full-featured than jest-fetch-mock.

Comment: the problem with fetch-mock and almost all other modules for mocking fetch is that they demand way too much setup. They should do away with `matcher` and automatically intercept all fetch calls. I don't want to have to duplicate my Express setup in a unit test just to ensure the code being tested receives a legit Response object.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by adding `isomorphic-fetch`.

```
$ npm install --save isomorphic-fetch
```

and using it like

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
...
fetch('http://foo.com');
```

whatwg-fetch might work as well

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. How do you mock `fetch` in your tests?

Comment: The original question was loaded because the user was also having "ReferenceError: fetch is not defined" error.

Bringing in isomorphic-fetch could be a step towards the solution, depending on what flavor of mocking fetch is used. For example, if using MSW, then this is all that's required to get fetch resolving and have MSW intercept fetch requests.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to test resolve and reject cases, for this first you mock the fetch behaviour and then use *Jest*'s *rejects* and *resolves* methods with with assertion block

```
function fetchTodos() {
  return fetch(`${window.location.origin}/todos.json`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

```
describe('fetchTodos', () => {
  it('returns promise resolving to parsed response', () => {
    global.fetch = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ json: () => ''}))
    expect(fetchTodos()).resolves.toBe('');
  })
  it('returns promise handling the error', async () => {
    global.fetch = jest.fn(() => Promise.reject(''))
    expect(fetchTodos()).rejects.toBe('')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As @ArthurDenture recommended, you can use [fetch-mock](http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/), but there are some additional packages you will need to install to make it work with React Native and Jest:

```
$ npm install --save-dev fetch-mock
$ npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-runtime
$ npm install --save-dev babel-preset-env
```

You can then mock fetch requests in your tests. Here is an example:

```
// __tests__/App.test.js
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  fetchMock.mock('*', 'Hello World!');
  const rendered = renderer.create(<App />).toJSON();
  expect(rendered).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to problems using fetch-mock with jest, I've release [fetch-mock-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-mock-jest). It basically gives the full [fetch-mock api](http://wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock), but with a few jest-specific helpers, and works out of the box with jest, without needing to do any tricky wiring yourself

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the react-testing-library documentation, you can use the jest.spyOn() function, which will mock the fetch function only for the next time it is called.

```
const fakeUserResponse = {token: 'fake_user_token'}
jest.spyOn(window, 'fetch').mockImplementationOnce(() => {
  return Promise.resolve({
    json: () => Promise.resolve(fakeUserResponse),
  })
})
```

[react-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library)

Comment: OP asked mock for *React Native*, not web. RN doesnt have `window` object.