# Enzyme: on simulating "click", test asynchronously changed state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, create-react-app

I am trying to test a `state` value (say: `state.name`) which asynchronously changes on a button click.

**Initially**

- `state.name`is `"Random Value"`
- When a ***button is clicked*** `state.name` changes to `"peter"` from `"Random Value"`
- works as expected in browser
- Need it to work the same on `button.simulate('click')` in my ***test***

## My component `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    state = {name: "Random Value"};
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div>{this.state.name}</div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>GetData</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        const currentContext = this;
        fetch('http://api-call/getdata')
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(jsonData) {
                // jsonData.name = "peter"
                currentContext.setState({name: jsonData.name});
            })
    }
}

export default App;
```

## The test file `App.test.js`

```
describe('<App/>', () => {    
    it('should handle click correctly', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<App />);

        expect(wrapper.find('button').length).toBe(1);

        expect(wrapper.state().name).toEqual("Random Value");
        wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
        expect(wrapper.update().state().name).toEqual("peter");
    });
});
```

## Result:

```
// FAILED!

Expected value to equal:
      "peter"
Received:
      "Random Value"
```

## What else have I tried?

All sorts of solutions out there like using `async await`, `setImmediate` and then `wrapper.update()` and many other things. Maybe I did something wrong or missed something. Anyways I have spent an evening trying to do it. I need help from `enzyme` experts.

Thanks

Comment: do you mock response? or do you send real request?

Comment: No didn't mock.

Comment: is it unit test or e2e? I guess unit test. then you need to mock request

Comment: how to mock `fetch`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36069731/how-to-unit-test-api-calls-with-mocked-fetch-in-react-native-with-jest

Comment: I will try to do that, but please add an answer if possible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you need mock `fetch` somehow. Sending real request not only breaks isolation of unit-tests and adds risks of inconsistency. It's also harder to wait for response when you don't know when it may finish. There are different ways to achieve that. [`jest-fetch-mock`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-fetch-mock) is one of them.

Also I advice you don't check for `state` but rather check for `render()` results.

```
function getName(wrapper) {
    return wrapper.find('.App > div').at(0).props().children;
} 

it('should handle click correctly', async () => {
    fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify({ name: '12345' }));
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);

    expect(wrapper.find('button').length).toBe(1);

    expect(getName(wrapper)).toEqual("Random Value");
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    await Promise.resolve();
    expect(getName(wrapper)).toEqual("peter");
});
```

What's going on here. `await Promise.resolve()` is just just waits until all promises already resolved are run. It means without that our mocked response will not run between button click and `expect` runs.

Another way to get positive result is making `handleClick()` to return Promise we can await for:

```
...
handleClick = () => {
    const currentContext = this;
    return fetch('http://api-call/getdata')
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(jsonData) {
            // jsonData.name = "peter"
            currentContext.setState({name: jsonData.name});
        })
}
....
it('should handle click correctly', async () => {
     ....
    expect(getName(wrapper)).toEqual("Random Value");
    await wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(getName(wrapper)).toEqual("peter");
});
```

or without async-await syntax:

```
it('should handle click correctly', () => {
     ....
    expect(getName(wrapper)).toEqual("Random Value");
    return wrapper.find('button').simulate('click').then(() => {
        expect(getName(wrapper)).toEqual("peter");
    });
});
```

But I really don't like this way since event handler have to return a Promise that it typically does not do.

More on microtasks(Promises)/macrotasks(timers, events) yuo may read here: https://abc.danch.me/microtasks-macrotasks-more-on-the-event-loop-881557d7af6f

More on testing async code in jest you better check their docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous